# What is the endpoint for location services in Alexa?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am using location services permission in Alexa developer portal for getting real-time user location.
What is the endpoint for location services?
Endpoints for ex: /v1/devices/*deviceId*/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode

In the docs, I am getting endpoints for other permissions such as Email, Name and Device address.
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html

I have referred: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/location-services-for-alexa-skills.html 
also https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/f23d0796-6c98-40d4-b499-e198b347a998/location-services-launch but not getting proper help.
What can be done?

Comment: You are not accessing this via an API call, The location services operate via permissions, the user has to allow polling and have location enabled in both your application and their mobile device. The geo-coordinates are then returned as part of a JSON object in your interaction context.

Comment: Can you send me a code snippet for backend in Python? I have tried doing for location services via permissions. The geo-coordinates are not returned in JSON it is empty.

Comment: @ChuckLaPress Can you send me a code snippet for backend in Python? I have tried doing for location services via permissions. The geo-coordinates are not returned in JSON it is empty.